# C puzzle; multiplying Char's

Tags: c, char, arithmetic-expressions

Recently my C professor gave us the following puzzle:

```
char c1, c2, c3;

c1 = 'a';
c2 = 'e';
c3 = c1 * c2;
printf("%c",c3);
```

Answer: E

However, I'm a bit confused as to how this would be solved intuitively other than having the product already memorized. From what I've researched the int values of the characters 'a' and 'b' are 97 and 101 respectively and 'E' being 69 which is what I'm having a rough time understanding how that result was achieved.

Comment: What's the value of the product, in binary? How many bits can be stored in a char? What happens when you assign an int to a char?

Comment: @sharth I don't think so. In `c1 * c2`, the type of result is `int`. and it is casted to `char`. Both `(signed int)0x2645` and `(signed char)0x45` are positive number.

Comment: BTW: the code `“%c”` likely should be `"%c"`.  Note the quote marks.

Comment: "the int values of the characters 'a' and 'b' are 97 and 101 respectively" You mean 'a' and 'e'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first, `97 * 101` is `9797`. (In hex, `0x2645`).

and `char` is 1byte. so `0x2645` become `0x45`.

`0x45 == 69 == 'E'`. That's it.

Comment: Wow neat! I see whats going on now. Thank you! Next time I'll be sure to check hex codes and use the sizeof operator.

Comment: @brto and you'll have to check `signed`/`unsigned`. Sometimes they make some problems.. and if you think my answer is a correct answer to your question, you can accept a question by clicking the check button.

Comment: @brto please see KeithThompson's answer. Strictly speaking, he's answer is correct but I think your professor didn't think that...

Answer (score 2):

```
char c1, c2, c3;

c1 = 'a';
c2 = 'e';
c3 = c1 * c2;
```

The result is implementation-defined, but likely to be `'E'`.

The C language does not specify the numeric values of the characters `'a'`, `'e'`, and `'E'` (or of any character other than the null character `'\0'`). For a system that uses an ASCII-based character set, the values are `97`, `101`, and `69`, respectively, but on a system that uses EBCDIC the values will be quite different.

Assuming an ASCII-compatible character set, the values of `c1` and `c2` will be promoted to `int` before the multiplication. The result of the multiplication is `9797` decimal, or `0x2645` in hex.

The assignment converts that result from `int` to `char`. If `char` is a signed type (as it commonly is), the result of the conversion is implementation-defined, but it's typically done by discarding all but the low-order bits. If `char` is an unsigned type, the conversion is well defined, and is reduced modulo `CHAR_BIT + 1` (very likely to be module 256).

The value assigned to `c3` is *probably* going to be `0x45`, or `69` in decimal, or `'E'` as a character (again assuming an ASCII-compatible character set).

So the output is `E` *if* a number of assumptions are satisfied:

- The implementation uses an ASCII-based character set (could be ASCII, or Latin-1, or Windows-1252, or Unicode, or ...);
- Either plain `char` is unsigned, or it's signed and the conversion from `int` to `char` discards the high-order bits; and
- `CHAR_BIT == 8`

And finally:

- Somebody was willing to write silly code that multiplies `char` values, stores the product back in a `char` object, and prints the result. Such code may be useful for testing your understanding of C, but it has no practical use (something that's true of a lot of class exercises).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
97 * 101
9797
9797 % 256
69
quit
```

`char` is 8 bits, allowing for a maximum number 256.  When you multiply 97 and 101, you get 9797.  The significant bits in the binary representation of 9797 are lost due to 8-bit arithmetic giving you 69 which is `E`.

Comment: On _many_ systems, `char` is 8-bit signed allowing a max value of 127.  On 8-bit unsigned systems, `char` has a max value of 255.  Never yet came across a system with a char max number of 256.